# Python requests: как парсить "авито"?

Tags: php, python, парсер

Не получается средствами `python` и библиотеки `requests` сделать запрос на авито: всегда возвращается ответ 403, хотя средствами php-curl я получил нужный мне код ответа 200

Headers'ы в `python` разные пробовал, но все тщетно...

Код **python**:

```
headers={'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36'}

r=requests.get('https://www.avito.ru//omsk/avtomobili?radius=200',headers=headers)
print(r)
```

код **php**:

```
$agent='Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36';
$c=curl_init('https://www.avito.ru/omsk/avtomobili?radius=200');
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
curl_setopt($c,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
$response=curl_exec($c);
curl_close($c);
echo $response;
```

Comment: Исправь на headers=head(Твоя переменная)

Comment: забыл исправить,когда вставлял код как пример,но сути не меняет,все равно получаю 403 ошибку

Answer (score 5):

Requests в Python по умолчанию использует устаревший протокол TLS V1. Для корректной работы парсера рекомендую вам использовать TLS не ниже V1.2.

Пример:

```
import ssl
import requests

from requests.adapters import HTTPAdapter
from requests.packages.urllib3.poolmanager import PoolManager
from requests.packages.urllib3.util import ssl_

CIPHERS = """ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA"""

class TlsAdapter(HTTPAdapter):

    def __init__(self, ssl_options=0, **kwargs):
        self.ssl_options = ssl_options
        super(TlsAdapter, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def init_poolmanager(self, *pool_args, **pool_kwargs):
        ctx = ssl_.create_urllib3_context(ciphers=CIPHERS, cert_reqs=ssl.CERT_REQUIRED, options=self.ssl_options)
        self.poolmanager = PoolManager(*pool_args, ssl_context=ctx, **pool_kwargs)

session = requests.session()
adapter = TlsAdapter(ssl.OP_NO_TLSv1 | ssl.OP_NO_TLSv1_1)
session.mount("https://", adapter)

try:
    r = session.request('GET', 'https://www.avito.ru')
    print(r.text)
except Exception as exception:
    print(exception)
```